# gatsby-source-wordpress plugin: I cant pull data from WP into Gatsby (error with connection)

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am testing how Gatsby and WP work together and I checked the example coming from the official plugin documentation ([Wordpress example on Github](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-wordpress))

I am hosting locally using **MAMP** with ports set on **80 & 3306**.

I know the error is in my gatsby-config.js on the **baseUrl**, because I tried to change it to a dummy website (live) and the issue was solved. So I guess something goes wrong when trying to get WP data from localhost. Here is my gasby-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        /*
          * The base URL of the WordPress site without the trailingslash and the protocol. This is required.
          * Example : 'dev-gatbsyjswp.pantheonsite.io' or 'www.example-site.com'
          */
        baseUrl: `localhost`,
        protocol: `https`,
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        useACF: false,
        searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
          sourceUrl: "http://localhost",
          replacementUrl: "https://localhost:8000",
         },  
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

This is the error I get in terminal:
[image: error]

**What I have tried**:

- Changed ports on MAMP to default (Apache: 8888, Nginx: 7888, MySQL: 8889) but than I can't open m WP site at all (I get a server error when typing localhost:8888 in search bar)
- Change baseUrl to a dummy live website: issue was than solved, but I need it to work on localhost
- Change the protocol to http (instead of https) because I read a similar thread here on Stack, but I still get the same error
- Migrating my WP site to temporary domain with Flywheel and using that baseUrl instead (which became testSite123.flywheelsites.com) but again, same error.

I feel a bit out of options, any idea is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few trials you can do:

- Revert or undo your MAMP ports to default so the `baseUrl` will become: `http://localhost:8888` (notice the port).
- Disable the PhpMyAdmin plugins
- Stop the SQL service to avoid potential concurrency conflicts